# How to embed an Angular2 app into a php template resolving relative urls?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

I have a weird implementation. I have a website built in PHP (http://phpsite.com) and it has a template with a header and footer and sidebar etc with a content area where I place my compiled angular2 app files (hosted at http://awss3bucket.com). We are hosting the angular2 app in a separate S3 bucket and are loading the JavaScript files on http://phpsite.com.

Essentially the php file looks like this:

```
<html><head></head>
<body>
<?php include "../header.php"; 
include "../sidebar.php";
<app-root>Loading...</app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://awss3bucket.com/inline.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://awss3bucket.com/polyfills.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://awss3bucket.com/styles.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://awss3bucket.com/vendor.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://awss3bucket.com/main.bundle.js"></script></body></html>
```

When I tried this implementation with the bundled angular files on the same filesystem as the phpsite.com website, it works perfectly fine. But when I try to load them from the S3 bucket, then the relative links that are used in the template file and css files break because they get generated as relative urls and the assets are not on the original.

So my question is, is there a way to change where each component's relative url points to? I can't set a base url because then it'll mess up the assets that are already existing on phpsite.com. For the time being we are using iframe but that is not ideal.

Thanks!